# Can an .env value start with the "=" symbol?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I have a password that looks something like this: `=nh7G&Gsd!d-d`

In Laravel's .env, is it legal to set this value like this:

```
DB_PASSWORD==nh7G&Gsd!d-d
```

Or is this the preferred way:

```
DB_PASSWORD="=nh7G&Gsd!d-d"
```

I am asking because neither option currently works for me (so I want to rule this out as a reason), and also for posterity's sake.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the password inside single quotes?

Comment: Quotes should work fine. I think under the hood Laravel uses the phpdotenv library: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: use quotes and run `php artisan  config:cache` to apply changes

Comment: Quotes should definetly work, I agree with @RubenDanielyan have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Quotes are not required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `.env` file, the quotes are optional. We can give quotes if we use whitespaces in values. In your case `==` you can use double quotes for human readability.

It doesn't have any other reasons.

Comment: This is actually correct. It turned out my connection was failing for an unrelated reason, and when I fixed it it worked even without any quotes, i.e. with `DB_PASSWORD==nh7G&Gsd!d-d`. Kudos to Laravel for making this thing so resilient, I guess.

Comment: @jovan hopes this helps